# [PyCharm]: detach debugger from cosole

Tags: python, debugging, ide, pycharm

I run a python console in PyCharm and attach the debugger to it by clicking on the green debugger button in the left pane of the console window.

Debugging this way works great!

But there seems not to be an option to detach the debugger from the console.
When I change the code or stop the debugger by mistake I am not able to reattach it because the debugger button on the left pane is still pressed :(

Therefore I have to run a new python console, redoing all the stuff done before (importing modules, scripts etc.), attaching the debugger.

It would be nice to have an option to detach the debugger from a python console, change some code and reattach it.

Does anyone have any ideas on this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with some implications and somehow cumbersome user experience IMHO.

Once you initiated a debug session from the Python console in PyCharm you can detach the debugger from the debugger window **but** you won’t see the debugger window nor be able to focus it even using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> unless you hit some breakpoint that you have to somehow set.

Once you reach a breakpoint, and the debugger takes control, you can press the red **×** on the left panel of the debugger window.

[image]

Then you will be asked:

[image]

You can press the `Disconnect` button that will detach and terminate the debugger **but** the debugger button in your original console will remain pressed until you restart that console.

You’re welcome to [request a feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23PY%20) for PyCharm and I will surely give it my vote.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I said: it is not possible to detach the debugger with a chance to reattach it without restarting the console - and loosing all variables. Imho it's more like a bug than a change request :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone wondering how to do this in new incarnations of PyCharm (mine is version 2021.3.2) can find it by clicking the little 'x' button on the tab created for the attached process, which will bring up the 'Terminate/Disconnect/Cancel' popup as from the above answer:

[image]